# LINQ to SQL filter combobox output

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

OK so I've got 2 tables for this instance, Users{UserID, Name}, Company{CompanyID, UserID, Name, Payrate}

i also have 2 combo boxes, first one is for Users which Displays Name, and the Value is UserID
i need the second combobox to get the Names from the Company table, but only showing Companies that are relevant to the selected user. I cant work out how to get it to go...

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

What language? C#, VB.NET ? Is this a web app or Windows app?  Do you have associations setup in your datacontext to link Company.UserID (child) back to Users.UserID (parent) ?

Comment: this sounds like it would be better as a comment to the question instead of an answer :)

Comment: Yes im using C# WinForm app yes i have that association

Answer (score 0):

if it's asp.net and on .net 4, there's some [new support for doing the filtering declaratively](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429264)

if you can't or don't want to use that, then i'd make sure you're using a linqdatasource to populate and use the Selecting event on the LinqDataSource - in there, you can set e.Result to the specific linq query you want to return (against the company table, i assume), which in your case will include a 'where' for filtering to the UserID (selected value) from the other combobox

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it.

1. "cbat" is the comobox

var cat = from s in db.categories select  new{s.name};

```
        this.cbcat.ItemsSource = cat.ToList();
        cbcat.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        cbcat.SelectedIndex = 0;
```